# Wifi disconnection issue on some devices

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, modem, adsl-router

We are having strange issue on our home network. Wifi signal does not appear on some of our devices with signal status **out of range**, while it works on some devices at the same time.

**It works on:**

1. MacBook Pro
2. iPhone X

**Does not work on:**

1. Galaxy A8
2. Huawei Nova 3e
3. Sony Laptop
4. HP Laptop

**Notes:**

1. Usually it happens in the morning, when we first try to connect. But sometime it happens in daytime while using.
2. Restarting router resolves issue
3. Changing wireless channel also resolves the issue
4. The channel was set to `auto`, and I tried different channels (e.g. 1, 6) but same issue.
5. The router temperature seems to normal (tested by touching)
6. I'm not pretty sure but router seems to be **Tenda D301**

I was thinking to replace the router, but I'm not sure if the problem is with router OR somewhere else. So I am seeking for an Expert Opinion before taking any action, please assist!

Answer (score 0):

Is there a lot of WiFi Signals in your Area?
If yes, download a Tool for Wireless Assessment. Personally, I used NetSpot.

As per my experience, there is a lot of WiFi Signals in my area so it interferes into one or more Channels even when AUTO is set.
By using the Wireless Assessment Tool, you can see all the Wireless Connection in your area even from a Mobile hotspots. Try finding the channel that has less interference and test your connection from it.

Also, test first using 2.4GHz Channels. Not many devices support the 5Ghz Channels yet.

If ever you find only your WiFi connection is present after scanning, then test using 5Ghz Channel (if your router supports it). This one is longer in range.
If still unfortunate, before you replace the router, try to tweak the router by updating the firmware or flashing other but compatible firmware first. But I suggest you research further before doing so because routers could also be bricked.

Another work-around that I personally did at my Company is to set the Router to automatically restart on certain Time. However, not all routers support that function yet.

Comment: 2.4Ghz is longer in range, not 5Ghz (performance-wise).

Comment: thanks Tim, I'll try NetSpot tomorrow. My house is in very less crowded area. I have two neighbours within 100m range, one of them don't use internet, the second neighbour has internet, but they are using portable and usually they are not using at that time. I don't think, there would be a problem even if they are using because there are only two networks at a time. In other words, only my wifi signal are available most of the time and there is very very less possibility of interference. So what do you recommend?

Comment: Recommendations:
Try: Changing router location, Changing wifi name (SSID), Changing wifi password, Disabling the ECO mode from the router (if have), lastly try updating the firmware.
If everything yields the same result, start looking for a router that has a 'Scheduled Reboot Function'. I find it as a good maintenance feature for a Network device.

Comment: @Tim.Towers Is your native language German? It looks like you are capitalizing every noun, which is normal in German but unexpected in English.

Comment: @Spiff, No dude. I'm a Filipino, second language is English. I also don't know why I do that. It's always automatic to me, maybe I have a percentage of German blood? :)

Comment: @Tim.Towers thanks for your suggestions, I'll try those one by one.